# Deriving confidence intervals from a LOOCV of a GAM

Tags: confidence-interval, cross-validation, generalized-additive-model, point-estimation

Say that I have some observations, $y_1, y_2, ...y_n$ that are described using a generalized additive model (GAM). A Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation (LOOCV) is then performed where each observation $y_i$ is removed and then the GAM is refit to the remaining observations and the omitted observation, $\hat{y}_i$, is predicted. This gives errors $\epsilon_i=(\hat{y}_i - y_i)$ that can be used to calculate useful metrics of my model's predictive strength. For example, I could calculate mean absolute error (MAE):

$\text{MAE} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n|\epsilon_i|$

So, that's cool, but rather than a point estimate of the error like this I'm curious if I'm able to calculate a confidence interval for the error based on these calculated errors? If so, is this also possible for small data sets (e.g., $n<20$)?

Comment: Upvoted the answer, but why would you fit a GAM to 20 data points anyway?  In most cases it's hard to avoid parametric structure with such a small dataset.

Comment: Are you interested in other approaches? You could simulate from the posterior distribution of the GAM and the conditional distribution of the response. If the model is a Gaussian GAM, simulate a bunch of draws (for each point you want to predict at) from the posterior of the model (if **mgcv** use the `coefs(mod)` for the mean vector and the `vcov(mod)` for $\Sigma$ of a multivariate normal, simulate from that. Plug each of those into `rnorm()` as the `mu` argument and for `sigma` use the residual standard error of residuals from model. With enough simulations per point use `quantile()` for CI

Comment: I am interested in other approaches for estimating the CI and that sounds interesting. My model is indeed a Gaussian. Are you referring to the approach you adopt [here](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2016/12/15/simultaneous-interval-revisited/)?

Comment: Partly; though you don't need to do the simultaneous interval for what I had in mind, and in that post we were interested in the mean only. You can create a CI on *fitted* values just by posterior simulation - [see this post](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2016/03/25/additive-modeling-global-temperature-series-revisited/), but if you want a prediction interval you need to plug in the simulations from the posterior of the model (which are the mean of the distribution) into a random number generator for the correct response distribution.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Okay, I still trying to piece this together. (I appreciate your patience!) So, I'd generate a matrix of random parameters using `mvrnorm` with my model plugged into `coef` and `vcov` (e.g., `mvnorm(n.draws, coef(MyGAM), vcov(MyGAM)`). Then, I can plug these new parameters into my model to get a measure of uncertainty in the response variable by rerunning the model. But what values do I run these models with? The same ones used to create the model? (Apologies for being particularly dense about this.)

Comment: For each draw (i.e., predicted value), I then have the mean (predicted) value and the standard error that I can extract by `predict.gam`. These are plugged into `rnorm` and a load of values are generated and then plugged into `quantile` to produce CIs for each point. I'm still a bit confused how to turn these point-specific CIs into prediction CIs.

Comment: You need to couple that matrix of draws from `rcoefs <- mvrnom()` with the $Xp$ matrix returned by `Xp <- predict(model, newdata, type = 'lpmatrix')`, where `model` is your fitted GAM, `newdata` is a data frame of new values you want predictions for - if you don't pass `newdata` then you'll get the $Xp$ for the observed data. Then compute `Xp %*% t(rcoefs[, i])` (i.e. you do a matrix multiplication of the $Xp$ with a row vector of coefficients (hence the transpose, `t()`). If you do that for all `i` cols of the random draws...

Comment: ...you have `n.draws` from the posterior distribution of the fitted values from the model. (Each `i` yields a new set of fitted values for *i*th draw from the model posterior.) You can then summarise the `n.draws` values for each observation to say get the 0.025 and 0.975 probability quantiles which gives you a 95% interval on the fitted/predicted values. If your response isn't Gaussian, then you'll need to simulate from the required distribution using the fitted values as means/parameters for the relevant distribution. Note you probably want `vcov(model, unconditional =TRUE)`.

Comment: I'll try to find some time later today to cook up an example and post it as an Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume for the sake of the argument that your sample points $\epsilon_i$ are i.i.d. You cannot assume they are normally distributed unless you have a good reason to. $n=20$ would be too few to assume that their sample mean is normally distributed. This combination leaves you already in a tough spot to compute your sample mean and standard error which you need for a confidence interval.

Furthermore, your sample points are actually not i.i.d., the cross validation introduces pseudo replication. Since you did LOOCV and thus without repetition, the pseudo replication comes only from the fact that each sample point is predicted through a model that was trained on almost the same training set. (Your "test-sets" which are individual records do not overlap.) There are corrected resampled tests which correct for cross validation induced pseudo replication. They make your standard error larger and thus your confidence interval wider.

The usual standard error would be:

$$\sigma/\sqrt{n}$$

The corrected resampled one is:

$$\sigma\times\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{1-n}}$$

Your confidence intervals most likely will be so wide as to be useless in this situation.

If you had slightly bigger data-sets $n>30$, you could do a confidence interval since you wouldn't need to assume normality anymore. If you have one like this, just try and see how large your confidence interval is with the resampled correction applied. Otherwise stay with the type of measures you mentioned.

Comment: So, MAE is probably a more useful metric of model error?

Comment: If you had slightly bigger data-sets $n>30$, you could do a confidence interval since you wouldn't need to assume normality anymore. If you have one like this, just try and see how large your confidence interval is with the resampled correction applied. Otherwise stay with the type of measures you mentioned.

Comment: In the corrected standard error, the value under the square root is always negative, right? If so, isn't this a problem?